# Modifying SpreadsheetLayers Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, degrees-minutes-seconds, spreadsheet

I'm trying to make a small change in this QGIS plugin (https://github.com/camptocamp/QGIS-SpreadSheetLayers), but I did not succeed.
I have an ods spreadsheet in which the coordinates can come in meters or in degrees, minutes and seconds format (DD MM SS,SSS), separated by spaces.

In the first case the plugin imports the spreadsheet without problems, despite the decimal separator being comma. However, in the second case the plugin adopts only the value of degrees for latitudes and longitudes. I'm debugging the plugin for two weeks in an attempt to make this change but came to fail.

Can anybody give me a hint where I can make this change?

[image: First case]
First case

[image: Second case]
Second case

Comment: Which plugin? Who wrote it?

Comment: Sorry, it's a Qgis plugin. Spreadsheet Layers Plugin.

Comment: I've added an answer. There are, as usual, alternatives. Hopefully, one will suit you. In short, you can edit the plugin (possible), change .ods to .csv (very easy) or add a new function to the expression editor and calculate new decimal geometry fields, and then set the layer geometry from that. Changing to .csv format is really easy.

Answer (score 1):

1. The plugin does not appear to support DMS format. You could edit that, of course, as you have been trying to do. However, the delimited text layer format does support DMS directly. I would just save the .ods file to a .csv file in Excel or OpenOffice and load it from there as DMS. This is quite simple. Obviously, you could also do this in Excel or OpenOffice *before trying to load the data*.

---

2. An alternative is to load the .ods through the Spreadsheet plugin and then use the **QGIS Field Calculator** to create decimal degrees from DMS, and set the resulting X and Y as the layer geometry using the "Create Points Layer from table" plugin.

   There is a function in the **Expression Editor** (of the *Field Calculator*) to convert from decimal degrees to DMS. But there isn't one to go the other way.

   To convert from DMS to decimal degrees, you need to write a small function to use in the **Function Editor**, as shown below.

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def fromDMS(value, feature, parent):
"""
Convert DD MM SS.SSS to decimal degrees. V2
<h2>Example usage:</h2>
<ul>
  <li>fromDMS("3 4 56.78") -> 3.0824388889</li>
</ul>
"""
    _ = value.split()
    return int(_[0]) + int(_[1])/60 + float(_[2])/3600
```

Click on **Save and Load Functions** to store this as a new function that can be used in the *Expression Editor* of the *Field Calculator*.

You could then set X as a new decimal value in the Field Calculator via

```
   fromDMS(Longitude)
```

and also set Y from

```
   fromDMS(Latitude)
```

Now run the **Create Points Layer from Table** plugin to set the geometry of the table from these values (X,Y).

---

3. There is also a Processing plugin where you can set the geometry from a function. In the Processing Toolbox, look for **Geometry by Expression**. If you have created **fromDMS** as shown above, you can use it here with the expression:

   ```
    geom_from_wkb(geom_to_wkb(make_point(fromDMS(LongitudeDMS), fromDMS(LatitudeDMS))))
   ```

---

The first option above is much easier, unless you have a lot of .ods files. The second option requires more work.

If you really want to modify the spreadsheet plugin, then you could run the same conversion in the plugin and store that instead of DMS. It is more complicated, as the plugin searches for possible geometry column names (Longitude, Latitude, X, Y, etc). You need to intervene in this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I've been working with these worksheets for a while and proceeding exactly in the way described in item 1 without any problem. Really, in that way, it works great. The idea was to automate the process and improve in the future including beyond the layer of points, also a polygon layer, from these points.
From what I noticed; the dialog box of this plugin creates an xml file with the information collected in the dialog box itself and save it with a *.vrt extension.

Comment: Where is registered the name of the file to be opened, sheet name, number of lines to be discarded, number of rows to scroll, name and type of fields, and where to get the lat/long information. This is then called in the function:
I thought about working from there, but I’m still lost.

Comment: <layer = QgsVectorLayer(dlg.vrtPath(), dlg.layerName(), 'ogr')>

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="Perímetro_Dona_Carmem-perimetro_1">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">Perímetro_Dona_Carmem.ods</SrcDataSource>
        <!--Header=False-->
        <SrcSql dialect="sqlite">SELECT * FROM 'perimetro_1' LIMIT 173 OFFSET 11</SrcSql>
...
<Field name="Descritivo" src="Field12" type="String"/>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>EPSG:4674</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Field2" y="Field4"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
`

Comment: You can build a Processing Model to automate 1. the opening of the. ods file and 2. the addition of new fields.  Then it will feel like opening a file with decimal latitude and longitude.